# Element locator not found

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I use Selenium2Library with Robotframework. With my code source, I go to a web browser and after 2 windows open. Then I close one window after I try to click on an element locator on the window but the element isn't found. I have error : *'id=ggroup1Mon' did not match any elements after 5 seconds*.

```
Open Browser     http://10.70.150.34/avldisplay/MONITORING/Authentification 
Wait Until Element Is Visible      id=j_username
Click Element        id=j_username
Input Text    id=j_username     452

Wait Until Element Is Visible      id=j_password
Click Element        id=j_password
Input Text     id=j_password   463425

Wait Until Element Is Visible      xpath=//button[@type='submit']
Click Element        xpath=//button[@type='submit']

${az}=      List Windows   

Select Window       @{az}[1]

Close Window     

Select Window       @{az}[0]

Wait Until Element Is Visible       id=ggroup1Mon
#Click Element        id=ggroup1Mon
```

Comment: List Widows deprecated. You can try with Get Window Handles.

Comment: @Murthi I would agree with you had the person asking not commented that the Selenium2Library is being used. In that case this keyword is available.

Comment: @Search can you elaborate on what the content is of `@{az}`. It appears to me that the code is doing what it should. So it comes down to debugging the variables to see if they match expectation. Can you provide them pre- and post closing of your window?